# results of subquery in > operator

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to do the below:

```
   select count(1) from fact_table
   _PARTITIONTIME > (select max (calendar_date ) as date from control_table  
   where description = 'current year start date')
```

However it gives the following error:

> No matching signature for operator > for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE. Supported signatures: ANY > ANY at [3:17]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is to address: `No matching signature for operator >` error

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM fact_table
_PARTITIONTIME > (SELECT TIMESTAMP(MAX(calendar_date)) FROM control_table  
WHERE description = 'current year start date')
```